# How to replace first occurrence after skipping a first match using sed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

Imagine I have the following piece of text:

```
<Data>
    <Country>
       <Name>Portugal<\Name>
       <Population>10M</Population>
       <Sub>
          <Code>Y</Code>
       </Sub>
    </Country>
    <Country>
       <Name>Spain<\Name>
       <Population>30M</Population>
       <Sub>
          <Code>Y</Code>
       </Sub>
    </Country>
</Data>
```

How can I replace the `Y` to `N` from Country Portugal without replacing the Code from the remaining countries?

I've tried to use sed:

```
sed -i '/<Country>Portugal<\/Country>/{s/Y/N/;}' file.xml
```

but this is not replacing anything.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? How can I replace the first occurrence of `Y` AFTER matching the Portugal ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Avoid [parsing XML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use an XML processing tool like `xmlstarlet`:

```
$ cat foo.xml
<Data>
  <Country>
    <Name>Portugal</Name>
    <Population>10M</Population>
    <Sub>
      <Code>Y</Code>
    </Sub>
  </Country>
  <Country>
    <Name>Spain</Name>
    <Population>30M</Population>
    <Sub>
      <Code>Y</Code>
    </Sub>
  </Country>
</Data>

$ xmlstarlet edit --update '/Data/Country[Name="Portugal"]/Sub/Code' -v "N" foo.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data>
  <Country>
    <Name>Portugal</Name>
    <Population>10M</Population>
    <Sub>
      <Code>N</Code> 
    </Sub>
  </Country>
  <Country>
    <Name>Spain</Name>
    <Population>30M</Population>
    <Sub>
      <Code>Y</Code>
    </Sub>
  </Country>
</Data>
```

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I was trying with regex is that I do not have access to xmlstarlet and I have no means to install it. however, I have xmllint. You think it would also be possible with it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a range match.

```
sed '/<Name>Portugal</,/<\/Country>/ s/<Code>Y</<Code>N</' file.xml
```

(Edited to match updated requirements.)

Comment: Thanks for your help!! However, I made a mistake in the question.. :( With your solution, that would be OK, but I forgot that <Country> is parent and Portugal comes inside the <Name> tags

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<Country>/{:a;N;/<\/Country>/!ba;/Portugal/s/Y/N/}' /file
```

Gather up the lines for a `Country` then match those lines to contain `Portugal` and replace the first `Y` with `N`.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is really always exactly that format then all you need is:

```
$ awk '/<Name>/{f=/Portugal/} f && /<Code>/{sub(/Y/,"N")} 1' file
<Data>
    <Country>
       <Name>Portugal<\Name>
       <Population>10M</Population>
       <Sub>
          <Code>N</Code>
       </Sub>
    </Country>
    <Country>
       <Name>Spain<\Name>
       <Population>30M</Population>
       <Sub>
          <Code>Y</Code>
       </Sub>
    </Country>
</Data>
```